# create ERC-20 token from a contract function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20, error

I would like to do a function create contract with ERC-20 interface. 
But I have a few problems.

If anyone help me I’ll be appreciated.

Here’s the code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';
/*
library SafeMath {
    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}
*/
contract SubToken{
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    //function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ;
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);

}
contract MainContrat is SubToken {
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    mapping(address => address[]) public created;

    mapping(address => SubToken) public tokenlist;

    address[] public contracts;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint _totalSupply;

    constructor(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply)  public{
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals=_decimals;
        balances[msg.sender]=_totalSupply;
    }    

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view  returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }


    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
/*
    function createNew(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply) public returns(address newToken){
        SubToken newSubToken = (new SubToken(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply));
        created[msg.sender].push(address(newSubToken));
        newSubToken.transfer(msg.sender, _totalSupply);
        return address(newSubToken);

    }
    */
    /*
    function createNewContract() public returns(address){
    SubToken st = new SubToken();
    contracts.push(st);
    address(st);
    }
    */
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);


}

contract factory{
    address[] public contracts;
    mapping(address => address[]) public created;

    function createNewContract(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply) public returns(address){
    MainContrat st = new MainContrat(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply);
    contracts.push(address(st));
    return address(st);
    }
}
```

I have errors at my createContract functions. Errors is :

**TypeError: Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract. SubToken st = new SubToken(); ^----------^ browser/crtcont2.sol:29:5: Missing implementation: function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); ^---------------------------------------------------------------------------^ browser/crtcont2.sol:26:5: Missing implementation: function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance); ^------------------------------------------------------------------------^ browser/crtcont2.sol:25:5: Missing implementation: function totalSupply() public view returns (uint); ^------------------------------------------------^ browser/crtcont2.sol:28:5: Missing implementation: function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); ^-----------------------------------------------------------------------^ browser/crtcont2.sol:30:5: Missing implementation: function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); ^-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^**

Comment: because you're trying to instantiate an abstract contract.

Comment: what should I do ? Can you help me?

Comment: Well yes I can create new contract and its give me the inspiration :)

Comment: @BadrBellaj hey I changed my code and I got same results can you help me again please :)

Comment: @BadrBellaj      
 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73209/typeerror-trying-to-create-an-instance-of-an-abstract-contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can instead use a factory class which creates token as follows 
in this design subtoken is an abstract class, implemented by token class and in the end a factory class which will create different instances of token class.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}
contract SubToken{
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    //function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ;
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);

}
contract token is SubToken {
    mapping(address => uint) _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    mapping(address => SubToken) public tokenlist;
    address[] public contracts;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    using SafeMath for uint;
    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint _totalSupply;

    //constructor(string memory name,string memory symbol,uint8 decimals,uint256 _totalSupply) public{
    //    _balances[msg.sender]=_totalSupply;
    //}    

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view  returns (uint256 balance) {
        return _balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {

        return true;

    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return true;
    }

    //function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    //    return approve[_owner][_spender];
    //}



    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract factory{
    address[] public contracts;

    function createNewContract() public returns(address){
    token st = new token();
    contracts.push(address(st));
    address(st);
    }
}
```

you can find a better example under https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/tree/master/contracts/eip20